# How many keys to the French Bastille are still in existence?

Tags: france, french-revolution

France's national day on July 14th is called Bastille Day in English.

The day commemorates when a mob of people on July 14 1789 took a medieval castle, a symbol of Bourbon Royalty, in the opening action of the French Revolution.

**My Question is:** how many keys to the Bastille are still in existence today and where are they?

1. I know General Lafayette came into the possession of one of the keys and sent it to his friend and superior officer in the American Revolution, George Washington. [That key is on display at Washington's home in Alexandria Virginia](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/how-key-bastille-ended-george-washingtons-possession-180959811/), Mount Vernon, to this day, when it's not out on loan touring France.
2. [I found a second key at the Alexandria Virginia Masonic Lodge, also presented by General Lafayette a few decades after Washington's death.](http://srjarchives.tripod.com/1998-02/Dunaway.htm)
3. [I found a third key at Madame Tussaud's Wax Museum in London, where Madame Tussaud brought the key with her when she fled France due to the revolution](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/384240.stm)

Sources:

- [How the Key to the Bastille Ended Up in George Washington’s Possession](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/how-key-bastille-ended-george-washingtons-possession-180959811/)
- [11 Remnants of the Bastille You Can Still See Today](http://mentalfloss.com/article/57792/11-remnants-bastille-you-can-still-see-today)
- [Scottish Journal, Marquis de LaFayette and Two Keys to the Bastille](http://srjarchives.tripod.com/1998-02/Dunaway.htm)
- [BBC, Bastille Key Found, 1999](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/384240.stm)

Comment: Is there a pre-storming inventory of the keys (what they fitted and what they looked like) from the Bastille? Without it any key of appropriate age could be called a "Bastille Key".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time of its Storming (14 July 1789), the Bastille had about 400 keys.
Today we know about the following:

- H.S. Howell's 5 keys (Canada, but where are they now?)
- Bill and Lynda Grieves' 3 keys (Ohio, USA)
- Carnavalet Museum's 6+ keys (Paris, France)
- National Archives' 27 keys (Paris, France)
- Madam Tussaud's 2 keys (London, England)
- George Washington Masonic Memorial 1 key (Alexandria, Virginia)
- George Washington's Mount Vernon 1 key (Mount Vernon, Virginia)

More information about the Bastille's keys can be found in the book "George Washington's Liberty Key" and at www.LibertyKey.US